# Resource consuming process

Tags: debian, java, process

I have a Debian server hosting an AngularJS - Java application.

When I run the htop command I have the following process which consumes the resource and I wanted to know what this process is for?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/enFfR.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That thing is suspect. No sane application should run from `/tmp`, and considering that it seemingly loads libraries from next to itself, my first guess is that thing is a result of an intrusion of some kind. I would check the system if I were you.

Comment: thx for your reply. How can i do to check system ?

Comment: Check user entries, suspicious processes (you've already found one), and system logs, as well as network traffic. Unfortunately, a thorough the answer to that question is well beyond the limits of a simple remark, possibly even a post. If you don't know how to check your system for intrusion, you should contact someone who has experience in this matter. If the system turns out to be compromised, then you might want to read [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) and its answers.